# Flask SQLAlchemy relationship query

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, one-to-many

I have two models with a one to many relationship

```
class UserModel(db.Model):
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
...
    weekday = db.relationship('weekDay', backref="usermodel")

class weekDay(db.Model):
    dayname = db.Column(db.String(15))
...
    usermodel_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('usermodel.id'))
```

How can I return a specific weekday associated with a particular user.

The following query runs but doesnt seem to return the correct result -

```
 weekDay.query.filter(UserModel.username == 'tester').filter(weekDay.dayname=='Monday').first()
```

---

EDIT:
I finally learnt how to create a working query that meets my needs, how is my understanding in case anyone else needs this

using my models defined above I started my query with the child node and explicitly joined the parent to it using the select_from and join statement and then finally added in my custom filters to search for what I needed. Here is the query

```
  weekDay.query.select_from(UserModel).join(UserModel.weekday).filter(UserModel.username == "username_goes_here").filter(weekDay.dayname=="dayname_goes_here").first()
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have a user with id 5 if you want to get weekday which associate with this user then: 
`day=weekDay.query.filter_by(usermodel_id=5).first()`
`day.dayname` will give you day name associate with that user. 
If that you want to have

Comment: well yes but I want to add another level of filtering. That query will return the first weekday element for user Id 5. I want to be able to find a specific weekday element for user id 5